# Замена строки в файле нужным текстом

Tags: java, android

Работаю в Android Studio, пишу на Java. Имеется файл, в который нужно записать информацию. В файле уже есть несколько значений. Одно из них, находящееся в отдельной строчке, мне нужно заменить на другое. Но я знаю лишь 2 способа записи информации в файл.

Первый:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("textfile", Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

Второй:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("textfile", Context.MODE_);
```

Но проблема в том, что первый способ лишь добавляет строки в файл, что не подходит, а второй переписывает файл заново с этой же строкой. Конечно, можно использовать второй метод и перед записью нового значения считывать остальные и добавлять их при перезаписи файла, но я уверен, что есть более короткий путь.

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность? И что за `Context.MODE_`? Насколько мне известно, вариантов всего два: либо считывать весь файл, менять нужное значение и записывать обратно, либо воспользоваться [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), если известна позиция для замены и итоговая строка совпадает по длине с исходной.

Comment: возможно вам лучше использовать структурированный файл с доступом к элементам структуры - XML или JSON и соответственно классы-парсеры этих структур